# Visual Studio : How to switch between test / production databases quickly?

Tags: visual-studio, configuration, app-config, development-environment

I'm working in a solution which includes a windows service host project that uses a single app.config file which contains everything the service needs (logging configuration, WCF configuration, custom configuration, and, **connection strings**).

The way I actually work is when a user complains about something wrong in the production environnement, I edit the app.config file, modify the connection string so it points to the production database, recompile the service host project, then run the application in my dev environnment to see what's going on.

If I have to test things that would be too risky for the production environment, I edit again the app.config file, modify the app.config file so it points to the test database, recompile the service host project, ... you see where I'm going ...

To avoid the burden of editing the app.config file everytime I have to switch environments, I decided to create a "Production" build configuration and a "Test" build configuration. I added two additionnal config files, one for each environment, which are replicas of the main app.config file except that their connection string points to their respective database. I modified the pre-build event of the project to include code that copies the environment's app.config file depending of the selected build configuration.

I have two concerns about that method :

- If I have anything else to modify in the app.config file (WCF, logging, etc.) I have to remember to replicate my modification in the other file. (Big problem for me as I have as much memory as a red fish)
- I hate making the project more complex to work with because of the additional build events, additional files in the project directory, etc.
- Each build configuration outputs in a different directory. I hate having duplicates of the same code just to overcome that data source issue.

Anybody can suggest a simpler way to work with multiple environments ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I thought app.config was designed precisely to make it easy to customize environment issues (without having to rebuild or redeploy anything).  Q: Isn't editing app.config with notepad (or keeping two copies of the file, and replacing one with the other) the easiest way to go???  Q: Do you have a "diff" program (e.g. "windiff") to compare them, if you need to?

Comment: You are right about the fact that this is exactly why application configuration files exist. Maybe I am too much of a lazy person ? Editing the app.config file, finding the connection string line, and changing the data source name has become irritating over time. I just thought there was a faster way to switch data sources.